# Handlebarsjs left behind expression

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I am looking for a solution how to compile HTML template without ignoring unfilled data using Handlebarsjs.

For example:

```
var Handlebars = require("handlebars");
var html = "<div>{{foo}}</div><div>{{foo2}}</div>";
html = Handlebars.compile(html)({
    foo : "This is a sample"
});
console.log(html);
```

Is there available compiling option that could help me to left behind the expression?
Like that:

```
html = Handlebars.compile(html)({
   foo : "This is a sample"
},{isLeftBehindEx:true});
<div>This is a sample</div><div>{{foot2}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Expressions are helpers](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html)

   > This expression means "look up the title property in the current context". [...]
   >   Actually, it means "look for a helper named title, then do the above" [...]
2. When a helper is missing, an [internal helper named `helperMissing`](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#helperMissing) is called to replace the missing expression
3. You can pass [pass an options hash when you execute your template](http://handlebarsjs.com/execution.html#Options) to provide custom helpers.

Armed with that knowledge, you can for example replace your missing values with an arbitrary string representation:

```
var compiled = Handlebars.compile(html);
html = compiled({
    foo : "This is a sample"
}, {
    helpers: {
        helperMissing: function(o) {
            return '{{' + o.name + '}}';
        }
    }
});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/jrtrvmd4/

Or you can override the `helperMissing` globally if you prefer and condition its output on an optional flag you pass as a `data` option, for example `isLeftBehindEx` as you suggested :

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('helperMissing', function(o) {
    return (o.data.isLeftBehindEx) ? '{{' + o.name + '}}' : "";
});

html = compiled({
    foo : "This is a sample"
}, {
    data: {
        isLeftBehindEx: true
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jrtrvmd4/3/

Answer (score 0):

For reusing the built-in method of Handlebarsjs without redeveloping unncessary code,
I still use the following way to achieve my goal...

```
var Handlebars = require("handlebars");
Handlebars.registerHelper('foo2', function(val, options) {
    return "{{"+val.name+"}}"
});
var html = "<div>{{foo}}</div><div>{{foo2}}</div>";
//compile but stay behind the expressions
console.log(Handlebars.compile(html)({
    foo : "This is a sample"
}));
//compile and remove the expression as usual
Handlebars.unregisterHelper('foo2');
console.log(Handlebars.compile(html)({
    foo : "This is a sample"
}));
```